# Headers already sent in cron job solutions not working

Tags: php, cron

I know this has been asked tons of times here and all over the internet however solutions I found are not working and this has been driving me crazy for several months now.

I have a very simple PHP page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

I'm getting the nightmare errors `headers already sent` and `cache limiter` in my error_log. Although it doesn't affect the function of any of the scripts but it's filling the error_log so much. There is no error when running from browser.

I have tried the TextWrangler editor for Mac and choosing `Unicode UTF-16 with no BOM` option when saving. However, after creating the file using Textwrangler, making sure that the extension is PHP, and uploading the file to server. I tried running the file directly and I got the following in browser:

```
<�?php session_start(); ?>
```

So the file is not encoded properly. I don't know why. With regular encoding of UTF-8 from either TextEdit or TextWrangler, the header error would appear in cron job as stated before.

I write all the text myself without copying so that no BOM characters in the file. Is there any REAL solution for this error? Should I use an ANSI editor? Isn't the save as utf-16 with no bom option used to avoid this errors? Or this errors must appear if there is session in cron?

Lastly I use the following cron job in cpanel: `php -q /path/to/file.php`

Comment: sorry a typo...corrected

Comment: I'd try another editor. [Atom](https://atom.io/) is what all the cool kids are using

Comment: And How are you getting php code in the brower ? Are you sure?

Comment: yes...100% sure...working properly

Comment: But you shouldnt be seeing php code in browser

Comment: that's when using the without BOM option. Using the regular utf-8 doesn't output the actual php code

Comment: i tried using Notepad++ on windows with `UTF-8 without BOM` and `ANSI` encoding but both didn't work as well

Comment: `headers already sent` which file and line are mentioned in the error message? php has option to automatically prepend files before any code (listed in php.ini)

Comment: this file is only 1 line as you can see. the error as well mentions it's on line 1. It's really confusing. I contacted my host to check if they append any output or code at the beginning of the cron scripts and they are checking

Answer (score 0):

Calling your php script from cron will invoke PHP-CLI environment, which is not the same as calling the same script from the browser.
For example there are no cookies and obviously there is no session by default.

However if you still want to enjoy the sessions , there is a way. You can try this:

```
<?php
session_id ("temp");
session_start();
print_r ($_SESSION);
?>
```

If you give us information about the final goal or the use case behind this script we can help you more!

Comment: the purpose of sessions in my case is to post to Facebook on behalf of my app users

Comment: What this has to do with the sessions? Last time when I was posting to FB with cron scripts all that was needed was token for the user and specific permission for posting. I think FB changed the posting policy after that so now it is not possible to post without the user to be online and to explicitly approve the post. So doing this  with cron script is not an option I think.

Comment: In the old version of the Facebook PHP SDK 3+ you must include the `Facebook.php` for the SDK to function. This file initiates a session automatically even if you use the long-lived access token. So this triggered the header error each time I run from cron. Posting on users behalf like this was never allowed BTW but FB wasn't so strict about it. Now after the review system it would be enforced and I think they lowered the threshold of their spam filters to detect auto posting and ban those who post automatically.

Comment: if you open the old `Facebook.php` file you will find this block of code `if (!session_id()) { session_start(); }` but you didn't realise that i think because you don't have this headers error

Comment: FB had removed `offline_access` permission, so you can not post without the user to be online even if you use long-lived tokens. Here are the details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal

Comment: yes the offline_access has been removed from long time but the apps can still post to users with a long lived access token and i'm sure of this because i simply owned a horoscope app for the last 5 months that posted the horoscope automatically to users profiles without being online :)